# Attaching meta box to specific category/taxonomy in custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox

I have this case here and can't figure out how to do it. I have a custom post type with taxonomies and a meta boxes to that specific post type. The idea is some metaboxes to appear only when category/taxonomy is checked. Any help appreciate.
EDITED: I came with solution and this example is working properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(function($)
{
    function your_checked_categories()
    {
        $('#id_meta_field_1').hide();

        $('#id_meta_field_2').hide();


        $('#typeschecklist input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i,e)
        {
            var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/-([0-9]*)$/i);

            id = (id && id[1]) ? parseInt(id[1]) : null ;

            if ($.inArray(id, [1]) > -1 && $(this).is(':checked'))
            {

                $('#id_meta_field_1').show();

            }

            else if ($.inArray(id, [2]) > -1 && $(this).is(':checked'))
            {

                $('#id_meta_field_2').show();

            }

        });
    }

    $('#your_tax_checklist input[type="checkbox"]').live('click', your_checked_categories);

    your_checked_categories();
});
```

Comment: I've come to this article. http://www.farinspace.com/show-hide-meta-box-by-category/ The problem is I am using a custom post type. My function in edit above.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this please? I'm stuck on the same issue right now. I would really appreciate a response! Thank-you

Comment: Hi Matt. Yes, I came with solution. I edited the question as it should be.